# pass string variable without quotes in query vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

```vb
Dim StoreNoToUpdate As String
Dim Marsha As String

StoreNoToUpdate = "ABCXYZ123"

Marsha = "hi"

db.Execute "Update TblLodgingReport set [MarshaCode]=  'Marsha'  where [Store Number ID]= 'ABCXYZ123'"
```

I am trying to update "hi" at "ABCXYZ123" location. but its not pasting "hi", instead its pasting "Marsha".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim StoreNoToUpdate As String
Dim Marsha As String

StoreNoToUpdate = "ABCXYZ123"

Marsha = "hi"

Db.Execute "Update TblLodgingReport set [MarshaCode]='" & Marsha & "'where [Store Number ID]= 'ABCXYZ123'"
```

Comment: string concat should not be encouraged. Use SQL parameters instead

Answer (score 5):

You need to get away from SQL concatenation and start using parameters.

Query with parameters:

```sql
PARAMETERS [prmMarshaCode] Text (50), [prmStoreNoToUpdate] Text (50);
UPDATE TblLodgingReport SET [MarshaCode] = [prmMarshaCode]
WHERE [Store Number ID] = [prmStoreNoToUpdate];
```

Calling the above query in VBA:

```vb
With CurrentDb().QueryDefs("qryName")
    .Parameters("[prmMarshaCode]").Value = Marsha 
    .Parameters("[prmStoreNoToUpdate]").Value = StoreNoToUpdate 
    .Execute dbFailOnError
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following line

```
db.Execute "Update TblLodgingReport set [MarshaCode]='" & Marsha & "' where [Store Number ID]='" & StoreNoToUpdate & "'"
```

Its because `'Marsha'` means you are literally sending Marsha as string and not using the variable.